# SMARTY - How to display template variables

Tags: php, html, smarty

I've been working with the Smarty Template Engine with `display_errors = Off`. Turning it on, I realize that just leaving:

```
<li{$page['home']}>...</li>
<li{$page['about']}>...</li>
```

where,

```
$page['home'] = ' class="current"';
$this->smarty->assign("page", $page);
```

gives me an error, saying that `$page['about']` is not defined.

As of now, I see my options are to either turn `display_errors = Off` or to do this:

```
<li{if isset($page['home'])}{$page['home']}{/if}>...</li>
<li{if isset($page['about'])}{$page['about']}{/if}>...</li>
```

Any reason why I should use one over the other? Or any better solution? Thanks.

Comment: You could make the `about` template variable equal to an empty string.

Comment: Is this Smarty 3? I know in smarty 2 you would use {$page.home}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no difference...

BUT, it's much safer to define your empty variables as `NULL`.  This protects you from leftovers, or things coming from other pages that you forgot about later, etc...  It's just being safe.

A lot of people swear by making unused variables (that COULD be set) to NULL before starting to use them.